# Magento 2 - Attribute (custom) filter not showing products

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation, frontend-error

We have a shop with migrated products from M1. Now when filtering a custom attribute to make the options smaller, it gives me the error that it can not find products (see image).

[image]
The strange thing is that the default attribute from M2 (Category of Price) are working well.

Any one have a idea?

Comment: Try reindex and check if it works for you.

Comment: No, this does sadly doesn't work..